# World to screen coordinates

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to translate world coordinates to screen coordiantes, and I am using the following line:

```
Vector3 Vec = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```

for some reason the value of `Vec` is (0,0,0). Why is that?

Comment: Input.mousePosition is already in screen coordinates. It does not make sense as an input to the WorldToScreenPoint method, which expects a point in world space as its input. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @DMGregory I want to press on the screen, and in the pressed point, I want to spawn a game object

Comment: How far from.the camera should the object spawn?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go from screen space (mouse position) into world space, then you're using the wrong method.

If you want to place an object at a particular depth from the camera, you can use this:

```
Vector3 GetMousePositionInWorld(float depth) {
    Vector3 position = Input.mousePosition;
    position.z = depth;
    return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
}
```

Just be sure you specify a non-zero depth. If you're using a perspective camera, 0 depth from the camera means every mouse position maps to the location of the camera itself (the tip of the view pyramid).

If you want to place an object where the mouse "touches" an object in your scene, you can do this with a raycast or spherecast.

```
Vector3 GetMousePositionOn3DCollider(float maxDistance) {
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, maxDistance)) {
        return hitInfo.point;
    }

    return ray.GetPoint(maxDistance);
}
```